# Simulating Conflict in GIT

Tags: git, github

I want to simulate conflict in git while switching braches without committing.

I have a master branch where I have a few files which are committed.

I create anther branch and modify the files which are also present in the master branch.

I still have not committted changes in the other branch.

But when I try to checkout the master branch It allows me to do the same.

I have not been able to simulate a conflicting scenario.

Can anyone give the file contents and the modified version of the same file which would cause a conflict.

Comment: From where the other branch is created? Its starting point must be at least made at a commit before the last `master` commit

Comment: Yes when I roll back to an earlier commit and then try to checkout to master I get a conflict.How can I do the same without rolling back to a previous commit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conflicts happen when merging changes that happened on a same base, so to generate a conflict you need to start a branch from a commit that happened before the last commit of `master`:

If you have the following you can't get a conflict because modifications happened sequentially:

```
* branch tip
|
* master tip
|
* commit a
```

There's nothing to merge, it's either branch or master.

On the contrary, the following will trigger a merge conflict if `branch` and `master` have made modifications on the same portion of a file, because they can be unrelated:

```
* branch tip
|
| * master tip
|/
* commit a
```

The conflict will happen on merging `branch` into `master`, git won't be able to say if you want to take the modification of `branch` or of `master`, or both.